# Import Module : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python

I have the following folder strucutre. When I run createdb.py, I get the following:

```
    from wrapper.utils import ymlconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrapper'
```

```
Root
|-- wrapper
|   |-- utils
|   |   `-- ymlutils.py
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- jobs
|-- execute
    `-- createdb.py
```

Comment: What's your code like?

Comment: Is `Root` in `sys.path`?

Comment: No. Basic usage of code is ```from wrapper.utils import ymlconfig ddlMap = ymlconfig.getConfigSetting("DDL",'Database',"createmetadata") ```

Comment: @JohnGordon no. How do I add that ?

Comment: Trivially with `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Root` before starting Python. (The syntax will be different on Windows and in philistine shells like `tcsh`. Look for the `set` keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
import wrapper
from wrapper.utils import ymlconfig
```

Thank you all !